# How to get the list of blockheader

Tags: block-header

I know that i can use `getheader 'hash'` from bitcoin core, but i can't use it for all blocks, it's time consuming.
Is there a site where i can find all bitcoin blockheader? Like a blockchain site but shows the blockheader?

Help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Do you want the whole header in e.g. hex format, or do you want each field separated, e.g. `version = xxx, prevHash = xxx, ...`?

Comment: Hex formatted if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of Blockchain.com's API (formerly Blockchain.info).

You can access BTC blocks based on their block height via a URL of the form `https://blockchain.info/rawblock/<height+1>`. We use `<height+1>` because 1 is used as the index of the genesis block, which is instead usually referred to as block 0, as it is defined to have a height of 0.

By default, this endpoint provides a JSON dump of the data in the block, but you can get the raw block data as a hexadecimal string instead by appending the query string `?format=hex`. For example, `https://blockchain.info/rawblock/2?format=hex` will give you the data in the block after the genesis block (the block with height 1) as a hexadecimal string.

The block header is 80 bytes, or 160 nibbles (hexadecimal characters), so you can e.g. use `curl` to fetch the data, and then `head` to truncate it to just the header, and then save that hex string to a file:

```
curl 'https://blockchain.info/rawblock/2?format=hex' | head -c 160 > block-1.txt
```

You can use a simple Bash script to automate this for all blocks:

```
#!/bin/bash

latest_block_height=670288

for ((i=0; i <= latest_block_height; i++)); do
    if ! [ -f "block-$i.txt" ]; then
        curl 'https://blockchain.info/rawblock/'"$(($i + 1))"'?format=hex' | head -c 160 > "block-$i.txt"
    fi
    echo "Downloaded block $i."
done
```